# Indicator-multiload at 100% CPU after power disconnect

Tags: dell, indicator, cpu-load

I'm on Dell Latitude 3440 using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit. Whenever I disconnect power plug from the laptop the system almost freezes with `indicator-multiload` taking 100% of CPU. When I kill `indicator-multiload` the system returns to normal -- almost, because some actions (especially Chrome) are more sluggish than before the freeze. When I re-run `indicator-multiload` it takes 100% CPU again. So my suspicion is that the problem might be related to **acpi** or **interrupts** but I don't have skills to properly diagnose it. This behavior was not observed in Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: It turns out there are other related problems. The laptop does not suspend or poweroff completely, and the freeze happens also when ethernet is disconnected. I tried `noapic` and `nox2apic` kernel settings following advice on some website but it didn't work. Then I tried booting the **upstart** version of the kernel and finally I see some improvement.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is caused by power management kernel bug related to the Wake-on-LAN function of Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10). When power cord is disconnected (and sometimes also when ethernet cord is disconnected) the kernel goes into an infinite loop of ACPI attempts, almost freezing the laptop, and flooding syslog with the following messages:

```
r8169 0000:07:00.0 eth0: rtl_counters_cond == 1 (loop: 1000, delay: 10).
```

A more technical description, links to bug reports, and a proposed patch are here: https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/586315/.

Before updated kernel is released there seems to be no permanent solution, but as a **workaround** reloading the r8169 module seems to help:

```
sudo rmmod r8169 && sleep 5 && sudo modprobe r8169
```

This needs to be run after every power disconnect. Alternatively, if you can live without ethernet, r8169 might be blacklisted which prevents the kernel from loading it at boot.